# Java - ssl certificate with JAX-WS client

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have imported the self sign certificate from the server using keytool and all work well.

Problem is that it works only when the CN name is use "example.corp.org" for the https: url with JAX-WS client. 
I get an error if i try to use the server IP address:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"     com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

I understand why i am getting the error but for a varies reasons i need to use the server IP address to connect to it and not the CN name.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks
Alexis

Answer (score 1):

You should add Subject Alternative Name to the certificate

```
subjectAltName=IP:serverIp
```

Comment: how could i do that? I am guessing this is done using keytool? if i am correct would there be a workaround that i can do within the java code?

Comment: I should have also said that i have no control over the self sign certificate i download from the server.

Answer (score 0):

sort of resolve it... found the answer here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6411944

```
HostnameVerifier myhostnameverifier = new HostnameVerifier() 
{
@Override
public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) 
{
return true;
}
};
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(myhostnameverifier);
```